# Lua - search for key inside of multiple tables

Tags: lua

For my program, I have multiple tables inside of each other for organization and readability. These tables can look something like this

```
local buttons = { 
      loadingScreen = { 
          bLoadingEnter = function() 
          end 
      }, ... 
}
```

What I want to do is find the first element named `bLoadingEnter` in the table. I dont know that the element named `bLoadingEnter` will be in loadingScreen. I've thought of getting all the keys in the table then check them. I couldn't get that to work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is `bLoadingEnter` always in `loadingScreen`?

Comment: @Sacha Yes it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If execution speed is in any way relevant, the answer is:

## you don't

Looking up a key in a nested table takes *a lot* longer than looking it up in just a normal table. The next problem is that of uniqueness. Two or more nested tables can have the same key with different values, which may lead to odd bugs down the road. You'd either have to check for that when inserting (making your code even slower) or just hope things miraculously go well and nothing explodes later on.

I'd say just use a flat table. If your keys are well named (like `bLoadingEnter`) you'll be able to infer meaning from the name either way, no nesting required.

That being said, nested tables **can** be a good option, if most of the time you know what path to take, or when you have some sort of ordered structure like a binary search tree. Or if speed really isn't an important factor to consider.

Answer (score 0):

Okay try

```
for _, item in ipairs(buttons) do
    if item.bLoadingEnter ~= nil then
        return item.bLoadingEnter
    end
end
```

Comment: Sorry that's not what I mean. I'll edit the question

Comment: Sorry, what did you mean then?

Comment: I've found the answer. I'll post it later.